# C# project doesn't pickup latest F# type declarations in referenced library

Tags: visual-studio, f#

My "Coordinates" type that's declared in my F# library isn't recognized in my C# library:

I have performed the following steps:

1. I closed my solution
2. Deleted all my bin directories
3. Deleted my ".vs" directory
4. Reopened visual studio
5. Rebuilt my solution

After the above steps, my C# project still doesn't pickup the latest type declarations in my F# project.

In addition, I have repeatedly removed and re-added my F# project reference to my C# project.

Version: VS2019 Preview 3.0

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which VS version are you on and are you using Resharper? At least with 17 and RS this is a limitation. The refs are highlighted as missing, but the project builds just fine.

Comment: I'm using VS2019 Preview 3.0

Comment: What framework you are targeting in your F# and in your C#? It often happens when you are targeting from lower version of .net framework a higher version.

Comment: I updated my post with screenshots of the version numbers. .Net Standard 2.0

Comment: You might be better off creating another DU or record (or whatnot) for Coordinate rather than using a type abbreviation. My answer is below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the problem is in the fact that your Coordinate is a named tuple and no actual class is generated for it.
If you try to dissemble the library you referenced it would look like this:
[image: decompiled]
[According to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/tuples#interoperation-with-c-tuples), to interop with tuples it's enough to consume/return C# tuples.
So in your codes you can create a list of coordinates using C# tuple:
`var coordinates = new List<(Test.Latitude, Test.Longitude)>();`

Comment: Scott's problem isn't about tuples... he's created a type abbreviation that is not visible outside the F# assembly.

Answer (score 3):

The way you've defined `Coordinate`:

```
type Coordinate = Latitude * Longitude
```

is a [type abbreviation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-abbreviations) that refers to a tuple of `Latitude` and `Longitude`.

This type abbreviation isn't a real type, it's another name, abbreviation, or alias for another type. Nothing outside of the F# assembly in which it's defined can see the type abbreviation; it's not a real type inside the F# assembly.